# No two things/thing?

Tags: negation, double-negation

Which one is correct?

1. No two speaker speaks the same language.
2. No two speakers speak the same language.

Answer (score 3):

Number 2: No two speakers speak...

Contrast with "These two speakers speak the same language" which has the opposite sense, but makes it clear that speakers is plural.

It's a similar phrase to "None of these speakers speak the same language  as each other."

Related to [Meaning of “no two”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36375/meaning-of-no-two). That answer suggests that the sentence is of the form "no (object) is (property)"